# railsで全ユーザの「いいね」した画像だけを取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

現在いいね機能は実装できたんですが、
全ユーザの「いいね」した画像**だけ**を取得する事ができないです。
因みに、ユーザ１人に対してfavorite_postsを実行しないとエラーが出ます。

```
users=User.all
users.favorite_posts
を実行してもエラーが表示されます(rails cで検証済！)。
```

下記のindexテンプレ内で`<%= link_to user.favorite_posts, user %>`を表示したら、
次の様なモノが表示されます。これはどういう事なのでしょうか？
ユーザがいいねした画像**だけ**を取得出来ているのでしょうか？
↓
`#<Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f9e3617af30>`
こちらをimage_tagで画像を表示する事は出来るのでしょうか？
次の様な感じで表示出来ると思ったんですが、出来ませんでした。
`<%= image_tag user.favorite_posts.url %>`
どなたかご教授頂ければ幸いです。

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
    @users = User.all
 end
end

[users/index.html.erb]
<ul class="users">
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to user.favorite_posts, user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :favorite_posts, through: :favorites, source: :post
end
```

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
 validates :user_id, presence: true
 validates :img, presence: true
 mount_uploader :img, ImgUploader
end
```

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :post_id, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#<Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f9e3617af30>`というのは、ActiveRecordの機能であるアソシエーション（`has_many`など）を使ったときに生成されるオブジェクトです。これは`Proxy`（代理）であるので、実際のレコードではありません（この場合は`Post`）。
このオブジェクトには`each`を使うことができます。`each`を使うことで実際のレコードを取り出すことができます。

```rb
user.favorite_posts.each do |post|
  <%= image_tag post.img_url %>
end
```

---

```rb
users=User.all
users.favorite_posts
```

こう書くと動かない理由は`User.all`にあります。試しに`User.all.class`を実行すると、`User::ActiveRecord_Relation`が返ってくるかと思います。これは`User`ではなく、複数の`User`の集合です。
「いいね」機能はあくまで個別の`User`と`Post`を結びつけるためのものであり、複数のユーザーの集合に対して「いいね」概念は意味を持ちません。上記のように`each`を使うなどして個別の`User`レコードを取得してから「いいね」した記事を取得していくことになります。